# How to remove \n from a file on ubuntu?

Tags: file, ubuntu, sed, newline, hexdump

So I'll to the point. I have an csv file, and when I opened it on excel and on text editor it's showing the different line number. And I think it's because the \r or \n special character, and the different way to read file of excel and text editor.

So I want to try manipulate the file. I look with hexdump on ubuntu, there's a 0a hexadecimal (\n) or new line character on it. I want to remove it with sed function on ubuntu but it cannot be remove with that. Anyone know how to do it? Give me suggestion please....Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To remove `\n`:

```
tr -d '\n' < myfile
```

Comment: thanks a lot mr Bohemian, but how can if I want to count the number of "\n" substring or another special character, cause I've tried to use grep -c "\n" and that's can't count the special character.

Thanks....

Comment: @Kenny that's a different question - please ask a new question

Comment: oh I'm sorry thanks a lot....